# Doing a for loop in a sequential evaluation in c

Tags: c, for-loop, comma-operator

I'm trying to use the sequential evaluation operator (`,`) in C, and I want to perform a for loop in the first expression, as below:

```
( for(initialization;condition;increment) foo() , bar() )
```

But writing that line I get an `error: expected expression`.

I would not be surprised to find out this is an impossible thing to do, even though something making me dither is that I can perform a pseudo-if statement in the form of `logical_expression ? expression_true : expression_false`.

Is there any way to do that? Or do I need to create the for loop externally?

**EDIT:**

I have decided to update my question to provide more context about my problem.

I have two functions, let's call them `baz()` and `qux()`. `qux()` is the inverse function of `baz()`, so for any given input, `qux(baz(input))` should return the input.

Specifically, `baz()` takes an array of chars, all of them between `'0'` and `'9'`, and returns a representation of that number in a different format that's not relevant to this question. When we pass that different representation to `quz()`, we get back the original array.

So I want to build my own code to test an arbitrary number of cases and see if `qux(baz(input))` is returning the desired result. And I want to do it in *the least amount of lines of code possible* (just putting all lines in the same one, separated by semicolons, is not what I'm looking for).

I know I could use a framework like CUnit to do it, but I want to do it on my own. And I know writing my code in this way makes it unreadable, and obfuscated, but I'd like to do it as a personal challenge. So I write (do not try to understand it, it is almost unreadable code):

```
#include "my_lib.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i, errors_size = 0, str_size = 1;
    char *str, **errors = NULL;
    (str = malloc(sizeof(*str)*2) , str[0] = '1' , str[1] = '\0');
    for( (i = 0) ; i < 10000 ; ( i++ , (str[str_size-1] == '9') ? ( ( str[str_size-2] == '9' ? str[str_size-1] = '0' , str_size++, str = realloc(str, sizeof(*str) * (str_size+1)), str[str_size- 1] = '0', str[str_size] = '\0' : str[str_size-2]++ , str[str_size-1] = '0' ) ) : ( str[str_size-1]++ ) ) ) ( printf("Trying %s:",str) , (strcmp(qux(baz(str)) , str) == 0) ? ( printf(" pass\n") , NULL ) : ( printf(" FAIL, got %s\n",qux(baz(str))) , errors_size++ , errors = realloc(errors, sizeof(*errors)*errors_size ) , errors[errors_size-1] = malloc( sizeof(*str)*(str_size+1) ) , memcpy(errors[errors_size-1] , str , sizeof(*str)*(str_size+1)) ) );
    for ( ( printf("\n\nERROR SUMMARY:\n\nTried %d cases. %d errors found (%f%%)\n\n",i,errors_size,100.0*(((float)errors_size)/((float)i))) , i = 0 ) ; i < ( (errors_size < 100) ? errors_size : 1) ; i++ ) ( (errors_size < 100) ? (printf("%d.\t%s\t-->   %s\n",i,errors[i],qux(baz(errors[i])))) : ( printf("The amount of cases to show is too big.\n") ) );
    return 0; }
```

And that's only 7 lines of code, with the main part being executed in only two of it. I try to build a string of chars that begins at `'1'`, and increment it for each step. However, when I reach numbers like 999, I have to set it all back to zeroes and add 1 at the beginning. And the only way I can think of to do that is using a for loop.

One possible solution would be creating a function to increment `str`, but that would mean writing extra lines of code, which is not an optimal solution for my challenge.

Comment: `for` loops do not go inside parentheses. They are statements and cannot be used inside expressions. Remove the parentheses around the `for` loop. If the `, bar()` is supposed to be separate, not part of the `for`, then make it `; bar();`.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what my question is about. In my own C code, I need to include a for loop into a sequential evaluation, or else I would have to rewrite it all.
Is there no way to do this? Even without using a for loop per-se, but an alternative solution instead that keeps the sequential evaluation structure intact?

Comment: Please clarify whether you intend `bar` to be inside the loop or outside

Comment: I only want foo() to be part of the loop. Bar() is thought to be executed only once.

Comment: An example of code that is not readable - why so many brackets?

Comment: To condense all my code into the least number of lines I can - not a good programming practice, I know. As I have written above, I want to do it as a challenge, not as useful code for other programmers to read it. The code I included is only to provide more context, but my question still applies to the simple statement I wrote at the top.

Comment: If you want to minimize lines of code, just put all the statements on one line. There is no rule in C that semicolons have to be followed by new-line characters.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question then: I want to do it using the least amount of semicolons I can

Comment: Code golf and obfuscation isn't really the best fit for this site. Such questions should be asked at [Code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). "Non-challenge questions that are related to solving programming puzzles or a particular type of challenge are also on topic."

Comment: Perhaps making code readable helps in avoiding problems and also help us to answer you

Comment: I do not believe this is an off-topic question. I am trying to solve a challenge with the proper answer, but that doesn't mean my question is a challenge itself. What I am asking is: in a sequential evaluation, is there any way to replace a for loop so that I can do it in that place, not rewriting my code as separate expressions or using auxiliary functions?

Comment: @EdHeal My code example is not really to be unserstood. I will try to change it, but let me insist: my question applies only to the line at the top of my question.

Comment: You can use '#define S ;`, and than you can write main in one line :-). On a more serious note, consider using 'sprintf' to prepare the string, instead of using inline code.

Comment: @dash-o Yes, you are right: that would be a good solution for my example. However, the question is still left unanswered, as I am not specifically referring to strings in it, only in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between a statement and an expression is covered by many good answer to this post. Wanted to highlight few alternatives that will achieve the equivalent of converting the for statement into an expression.

Some Notes:

**This is not standard "C" - it's using GCC extensions.**. You might have to enable those in the build, if the build ask for strict standard compliant.

The OP does not provide the specific case, so it's hard to tell if there are other specific alternatives

**Option 1 - Statement as expression**

See: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs

```
int func(void)
{
    // Execute the loop as expression
    ({ for (...) foo()  ; bar() }) ;
}
```

**Option 2 - Using Nested Functions**

See: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions

```
int func(void)
{
    void foo_loop(void) {
        for (...) foo() ;
    }

    // Execute the loop as expression
    ( foo_loop(), bar() ) ;
}
```

The nested function foo_loop will have access to local variables.

**Option 3 -  Using a function call**

It's not clear from the OP what are the loop dependencies. If it's is simple (e.g, loop N times), possible to use a helper functions

```
void foo_loop(int n) {
     for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) foo() ;
}

int func(void)
{
    // Execute the loop in the function
    int n = 50 ;
    ( foo_loop(n), bar() ) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It does provide a solution, but sadly not the one I'm looking for. I guess my best bet, however, is trying to write an auxiliary function to perform the for loop, as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a semicolon in your actual code, but using the comma operator in a statement is perfectly fine, like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("%d", i), printf(" Hello\n");
```

Comment: No, I mean: I am doing a sequential evaluation here. So your code would be: ```( for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("%d", i) , printf(" Hello\n") );```, which doesn't compile. (As I pointed out in my question, I get ```error: expected expression```).

Comment: What do you mean by "sequential evaluation"? And why did you put parentheses around the for statement in my code?

Comment: You can read a description of the behavior of the sequential evaluation operator [here](http://learn.microsoft.com/lv-lv/cpp/c-language/sequential-evaluation-operator). According to it, that would be the way of writing your code (using sequential evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

You can only put parens around an **expression**.
Keyword-constructs, like `for` do not count as expressions.

As @mnistic suggested, you can write:

```
for(initialization;condition;increment) foo() , bar();
```

without the outermost parens.

***But you cannot put parens around a `for` loop.***

What is wrong with just doing this?

```
for(initialization;condition;increment) foo();
bar();
```

Why do you *need* to use a comma?

Comment: So, would there be an alternative way of doing a for loop inside a sequential evaluation? Or is it just impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking things here.  Statements are evaluated sequentially, so given your example, you can do so as follows:

```
for(initialization;condition;increment) 
    foo();
bar();
```

If the call to `bar` is part of some larger expression, then that expression goes where `bar();` goes above, and the `for` loop comes before that.

If this still isn't what you want, then you need to give us more context into what you're doing and why you think you need a construct like the one you're proposing.

Comment: I have just updated my question to provide further context.